# Close BinaryWriter if it only opened

Tags: c#

I want to do something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(binaryWriters[i].IsOpen)
            binaryWriters[i].Close();
    }
```

if I try to close binaryWriter when it already closed I catch exeption

Comment: What is `binaryWriters` here?

Comment: Maybe instead of closing it manually you should take an advantage of BinaryWriter implementing the `IDisposable` interface and simply use `using` clause? See examples [on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binarywriter?view=netframework-4.7.2). This is assuming `binaryWriters` here is a list of `System.IO.BinaryWriter`.

Comment: Just check `binaryWriters[I].BaseStream.CanWrite`. It returns false if stream is closed. More interesting might be to know why you keep them in an array instead of disposing them ASAP...

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: Don´t wait for a stream to close at some point. Why hold it open? Close it as soon as possible, this is when you don´t read/write anymore.

Comment: "when it already closed I catch exeption" - that shouldn't happen. It is safe to close a File (or Writer) multiple times.

Comment: You posted some invalid code an did not state a clear problem. When you have an error, always post full message and details. See [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Switch your code to:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        using(binaryWriters[i])
        {

        }
    }
```

Using implements `idisposable` and will close your binary writer stream at the end of the block.

Comment: But this doesn't match with a `binaryWriters[]`. You don't get control over the entire lifespan this way, the `using{}` is providing a false sense of safety.

Comment: All the using is doing is disposing of the object, the same way close does.

Comment: Yes, but not in an exception-safe way here. You only cover a part of the lifespan.  And it wouldn't solve the original problem of Already Closed, if that had been real.

Comment: Yes it is, because using opens the stream and closes at the end of the block.

Comment: No, a `using{}` will not open anything. It only manages the closing.

Comment: There is no exception-safe way in software, this is why try-catch-finally clause are here for. Using will not be able to cover all edge cases, only if you constantly check if the binarywriters are closed, which is not recommended. If you want a 'safer' way, issue a try - catch - finally and if the binarywriters are closed already, just continue with the work.